# Buildroot и стандартный toolchain который в Ubuntu 18.04 для arm

Tags: gcc, lib, arm

Такой вопрос собираю с помощью Buildroot rootfs для платы, собралось
Далее с помощью кросс компиляции тулчейнами которые ставятся из репозитория Ubuntu собираю thttpd сервер со встроенным и предварительно собранным таким же образом PHP
оно тоже собралось, но при попытке запуска на плате оно не работает, как я понимаю проблема в том что библиотеки которые идут в комплекте с родным тулчейном Ubuntu другие чем те которые идут в комплекте с Buildroot. Собирать свои программы статитески или как то можно решить это ?

Comment: Как я понял, вы при кросс-компиляции что-то тащите с хост системы на целевую.

Comment: что происходит при запуске?

Comment: @Pavel Gridin пишет типа файл нот фаунд. VTT та вроде ничего не тащу, только скомпиленный бинарь. Еще бы хотелось спросить как и чем лучше всего собирать рут фс для целевой системы ?